# Как посчитать сумму заказа?

Tags: lsfusion

Есть класс заказов Order

```
СLASS Order 'Заказ';
number 'Номер' = DATA STRING[10] (Order);
client = DATA Client (Order);
amount = DATA NUMERIC[17,2] (Order);
```

Есть "подчиненная таблица" класс OrderProducts по сути состав заказа

```
CLASS OrderProducts 'Состав заказа';
product = DATA Product (OrderProducts);
productName 'Наименование' (OrderProducts d) = name(product(d));
qty = DATA NUMERIC[5,3] (OrderProducts);
price = DATA NUMERIC[17,2] (OrderProducts);
amount (OrderProducts a) = qty(a)*price(a);
```

Как посчитать сумму заказа, и вывести в amount(Order) на форму?

Comment: Получить все заказы, взять их суммы и сплюсовать. Что именно из этого у Вас не получается?

Comment: Добрый день! А как у вас связан Заказ с Составом заказа? И еще, обязательно ли `amount` должен быть `DATA` свойством, может быть сделать его вычисляемым, не нужно будет тогда в него записывать по событию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Между классами `Order` и `OrderProducts` (кстати, может быть лучше назвать его `OrderProduct`?) должна быть связь в виде свойства, которое по объекту класса `OrderProducts` возвращает объект класса `Order`. Предположим, что такое свойство есть и выглядит оно так:

```
order(OrderProducts op) = DATA Order (OrderProducts);
```

Тогда сумма заказа может быть выражена таким свойством:

```
amount(Order order) = GROUP SUM amount(OrderProducts op) BY order(op)
```

либо

```
amount(Order order) = GROUP SUM amount(OrderProducts op) IF order(op) == order
```

Очень похожий пример есть в этой статье: https://habr.com/ru/company/lsfusion/blog/458376/#group

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, теперь все стало на свои места. Свойство связующее было, только выглядело оно вот так: ord = DATA Order (OrderProducts);